# Apply CORS filter to Tomcat 4XX response

Tags: tomcat, jersey, cors, basic-authentication, http-status-code-401

I have a Tomcat 6 server configured with BASIC Authentication serving a REST API through a CORS filter to an AngularJS frontend.  With valid credentials supplied in the header, everything works fine.  When authentication is not approved (401, 403) the CORS headers do not get attached, and the client is unable to determine the status code.  Is there a way for me to configure the CORS filter to affect these responses?  Does anyone know where I can find a graphical diagram showing how filters and authentication fit into Tomcat's architecture?

The error I get in Chrome is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKdVV.jpg (I don't have enough reputation to post the image)

---

The security is configured like so:

```
<security-role>
    <role-name>phys_user</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Rest Service</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>phys_user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

I have tried registering a custom ContainerResponseFilter with Jersey:

```
@PreMatching
public class ResponseCorsFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest req, ContainerResponse res) {
        Response.ResponseBuilder rb = Response.fromResponse(res.getResponse());
        rb.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
          .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");

        String reqHeader = req.getHeaderValue("Access-Control-Request-Headers");
        if(reqHeader != null && !reqHeader.equals(""))
            rb.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", reqHeader);

        res.setResponse(rb.build());
        return res;
    }
}
```

... and in the `web.xml`:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
    <param-value>cm.security.ResponseCorsFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

I have also tried using a CORS filter from a library:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET, POST, OPTIONS</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
        <param-value>accept, authorization, origin</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportsCredentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

if (method.equals(GeneralEnums.HttpMethodType.OPTIONS.toString())) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Status.OK);
        }

Add above line in your ContainerRequestFilter. It works like a charm.

And also look at this link.

[Jersey REST + CORS + Jquery AJAX CALL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25487006/jersey-rest-cors-jquery-ajax-call/25488235#25488235)